# How to remove 'noindex, follow, max-image-preview:large' in search page Wordpress 5.7 up

Tags: tags

Is there any way to remove '**noindex, follow, max-image-preview:large**' in search page in Wordpress 5.7 and up? As I want to make the search page indexed in search engine, but Wordpress 5.7 and up automatically add meta robot noindex, follow.

Please help and I am sorry for bad english.

Comment: Search pages can't/should be indexed if I'm not mistaken because they require user input to generate a search.  Indexers aren't going to execute a search to generate a list of results.